# Google OpenID connect url iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Guys. I am currently integrating google login into my app. I already get the google sign in button done on my app. But when I trying to use AWS, it says I need to fill in a "OpenID connect url" and a google client id. I already got the client ID. But what is the openID connect url? I don't know where [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSbdr.png)

Thanks

Comment: Let me explain more specifically, the service I am setting is called IAM. I am using google sign in service to allow my app users to login the app. The first field in the picture is the OpenID connect url. I don't know where I can get one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup an Identity Provider such as Google to provide mobile / web application access to AWS resources you configure two things:

1. Setup Google OpenID Connect.
2. Setup IAM Identity Provider.

The OpenID URL is the endpoint that the AWS Management Console sends authentication requests to. This endpoint URL is provided by Google OpenID Connect when you setup the service.

Go to this page to setup your OpenID Connect OAuth 2 credentials. Then make notes of the OpenID Connect URL and Client ID (Audience) to enter into the AWS IAM console Identity Providers page.

[Google OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)

Follow this link which discusses the endpoint URL:

[Google Endpoint for Authorization Requests](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#sendauthrequest)

The URL is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth

For more information on using Google as an IDP with the AWS Management Console:

[Creating OpenID Connect (OIDC) Identity Providers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I can login with aws google service. But I can't obtain user data with AwsGoogleSignin service. When I was using the original google service, it is a delegate that give me the users' data, for example, email, user's name

Comment: @Yingyong. I my answer is correct please close this question and then open a new question for AwsGoogleSignin.